# Android screen on when notification recived

Tags: android

I need to on the screen, when received a notification for my application. Is there any specific way to on the screen?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP) for the wake lock you acquire